# signal interruption in python threads

Tags: python, multithreading, signals, interrupt

Is there any way we can kill a python thread under execution without using C-Api?

in my program i spawned two threads which run two different scripts.
If a user interrupt(Ctrl+C) comes to the main process then whatever the state may be, the spawned scripts execution need to be stopped.I can not keep on monitoring on some flag/variable as the scripts execution will happen only once.

Comment: I think you want to set your threads to be [`daemonic`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon)

Comment: if they made daemonic, i don't have control over them. they will continue their execution even main thread exits. :(

Comment: That's the opposite of what daemonic means. `The entire Python program exits when no alive non-daemon threads are left.` So if your worker threads are daemon threads, the program will exit when the only non-daemon thread (main thread) exits

Comment: if you make them daemonic, then that doesn't apply (note `non-daemon`). In other words, if all that's left is alive daemon threads, the program will exit.

Comment: may be code snippet will help me.. am adding my sample code here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a `KeyboardInterrupt` wont fire until `join` returns. If you want to use join I believe you will have to use the timeout parameter which gives the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception a chance to raise. Then when the main thread exits from the unhandled `KeyboardInterrupt` exception, the program exits because the thread `t` is `daemon` (also, be careful how you spell d**ae**mon)

```
import time
import threading
import sys

def dowork():
    print "Starting Thread"
    time.sleep(10)
    print "finished threads"

t = threading.Thread(target=dowork, args=(), name='worker')

def main():
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    while t.is_alive():
        t.join(1)
    time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Edit

For multiple threads, just join on each one in turn

```
for t in threads:
    while t.is_alive():
        t.join(1)
```

Comment: hi @GP89, its not possible in my case, in my actual program i have multiple threads so putting join when alive wont work for me :(